# Symfony doctrine ManyToMany unidirectional mapping

Tags: symfony, doctrine

Well, back again, i'll try to simplify my question as much as i can.

First of all, i have 2 Entities

```
Post
PostRating
```

I've created unidirectional ManyToMany relation between them, because I only need ratings to be added to each Post, if I try to map Post to PostRating too, I get Circular Reference error.

> Post Entity, it creates 3rd table post_has_rating, no mapping inside PostRating Entity, It workes like expected, rating collection is added to each post, but if i want to find one rating, and edit it if needed, then it comes to be bigger headache than expected.

```
/**
 * Post have many PostRating
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="PostRating")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="post_has_rating",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="postrating_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true)}
 *      )
 */
protected $ratings;
```

> PostController thumbAction, simple word "ratingAction"

```
/**
 * Search related videos from youtube
 * @Route("/post/thumb", name="post_thumb")
 * @param Request $request
 * @return string
 */
public function thumbAction (Request $request) {
    $content = json_decode($request->getContent());
    $serializer = $this->get('serializer');
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $postRatingRepo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(PostRating::class);
    $postRepo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Post::class);
    $me = $this->getUser()->getId();

    /** @var PostRating $rating */
    $rating = $postRatingRepo->findOneBy(['userId' => $me]);

    /** @var Post $post */
    $post = $postRepo->find($content->id);

    if ($post->getRatings()->contains($rating)) {
        $post->removeRating($rating);
        $em->remove($rating);
    }

    $rating = new PostRating();
    $rating->setUserId($me);

    switch ($content->action) {
    //NVM about those hardcoded words, they are about to be removed
        case 'up':
                $rating->setRating(1);
            break;
        case 'down':
                $rating->setRating(0);
            break;
    }

    $post->addRating($rating);

        $em->persist($rating);
        $em->persist($post);
        $em->flush();

    return new JsonResponse( $serializer->normalize( ['success' => 'Post thumbs up created'] ) );
}
```

> Problems: `$rating = $postRatingRepo->findOneBy(['userId' => $me]);` this row needs to have postId too for `$post->getRatings()->contains($rating)`, right now im getting all the raitings, that I have ever created, but it Throws error if i add it, Unknown column

Should i create custom repository, so i can create something like "findRating" with DQL?

OR

Can i make Post and PostRating Entities mapped to each other more simple way, i don't really want many-to-many relation, because I don't see point of using it

Comment: I guess that a oneToMany relation should be enough since a rating is only from one post. Besides of that you could write your own queries in the Repository with either DQL or the query builder.

Comment: Thanks, ill just use one-to-many then, if i remember right, i already tried it, and got Circular reference error.

Comment: @FrankB this is actually the way you declare a OneToMany unidirectional relation. Annotation OneToMany is only used in bidirectional relations.

Comment: @KarliOts be careful on your column naming, here your user_id column actually contains a post id and not a user id. Could you be clearer on what you are trying to do ?

Comment: @OlivierC Well, im trying to do post -> has many likes thing, thumb up and thumb down, how can you tell that user_id contains post_id ? i discovered that too, how can i make it, so i have post_id named there, because if i change it to post_id then doctrine searches by user_id, dont know how is that even possible, if you want, i could provide more code.

Comment: @KarliOts, it is in your JoinTable declaration : you named your column user_id instead of post_id.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you want to keep OneToMany unidirectional here is my suggestion

create a custom repository for your Post Entity

```
namespace AppBundle\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class PostRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function findOneRatingByUser($post, $user)
    {
        $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
            ->select('r')
            ->innerJoin('p.ratings', 'r')
            ->where('p.id = :post')
            ->andWhere('r.user = :user')
            ->setParameter('post', $post)
            ->setParameter('user', $user)
            ->getQuery()
        ;

        return $query->getOneOrNullResult();
    }
}
```

Then in your controller:

```
public function thumbAction (Request $request)
{
    $content = json_decode($request->getContent());
    $serializer = $this->get('serializer');
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $postRepo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Post::class);
    $me = $this->getUser()->getId();

    /** @var Post $post */
    $post = $postRepo->find($content->id);

    $rating = $postRepo->findOneRatingByUser($post->getId(), $me);

    if (null === $rating) {
        $rating = new PostRating();
        $rating->setUserId($me);   
    }

    switch ($content->action) {
    //NVM about those hardcoded words, they are about to be removed
        case 'up':
                $rating->setRating(1);
            break;
        case 'down':
                $rating->setRating(0);
            break;
    }

    $post->addRating($rating);

        $em->persist($rating);
        $em->persist($post);
        $em->flush();

    return new JsonResponse( $serializer->normalize( ['success' => 'Post thumbs up created'] ) );
}
```

If you want your custom repository to work dont forget to declare it in your entity

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\PostRepository")
 */
class Post
```